"'indexName' is a required parameter for the AzureCognitiveSearch data source type." in Azure AI Studio playground chat
Working in Azure AI Studio, I created a Hub and a project for creating a custom co-pilot.  While testing in the playground and entering a prompt, I received the error "'indexName' is a required parameter for the AzureCognitiveSearch data source type."
How can I correct this?

Are trying in studio or any sdk?
